# Move LineSeparator to the bottom of the page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have LineSeparator which plots it on the top of the page

[image]

All I am trying to move the LineSeparator bottom of the page like

[image]

I wasn't successfully to set the absolute position to the LineSeparator.

So far:

```
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        LineSeparator UNDERLINE = new LineSeparator(0.5f, 92, null, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, -2);
        paragraph.add(UNDERLINE);
        document.add(paragraph);
```

Please give me some directions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to draw a line at an absolute position. Then why use a `LineSeparator`? Why not just draw the line?

For instance:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.moveTo(36, 36);
canvas.lineTo(559, 36);
canvas.stroke();
```

More examples can be found in "[The ABC of PDF](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc)".

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie, Chose a wrong option to do the job! your answered worked superb!, thanks for your time and directions.